# Facebook logout redirection not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, logout

I am currently trying to implement facebook login/logout on my website. However, I have an issue with redirections, I wrote :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
        window.location = '/loginfb';
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function () {
        window.location = '/logoutfb';
    });
```

in  `window.fbAsyncInit = function() { ... }` after FB.init

The problem is that when i logout, my site redirects to the `loginfb` url. 
Where could that come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it so

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    console.log('auth.login: ' + response);
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
    console.log('auth.logout: ' + response);
});
```

then see console browser what has been written.